# Two checkboxes acting as one

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have two checkboxes on a page and I want them to act as only one. For example, I select one, and the other is selected automatically, and vice-versa.
I've managed to select both of them at once, but I can't seem to figure out a way to deselect them at once.

And what's bothering me the most, is that it's probably a super simple line of code that I'm simply not remembering.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Post the relevant code so people can help.

Comment: Also, check <label for="checkbox_id" />

Comment: How are you setting them?  Un-setting them may be just a case of changing `true` to `false`.

Comment: Note that ["Is this possible?" is usually a sign of a bad question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291599/215552).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(".test").change(function () {
    $(".test").attr("checked", this.checked);
  });

<input type='checkbox' class='test'>A<br />
<input type='checkbox' class='test'>B<br />
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: Also, one should use `prop('checked', this.checked)` for Boolean attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in pure javascript:

```js
// Select all checkboxes using `.checkbox` class
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');

// Loop through the checkboxes list
checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
    // Then, add `change` event on each checkbox
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        // When the change event fire,
        // Loop through the checkboxes list and update the value
        checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
            checkbox.checked = event.target.checked;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Item 1</label>
<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Item 2</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#check_one').change(function() {
   $('#check_two').prop('checked', $('#check_one').prop('checked'));
  });
  
 $('#check_two').change(function() {
    $('#check_one').prop('checked', $('#check_two').prop('checked'));
  });  
});
```

```html
<form>
<label>Simple checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check_one" />
<label>Complicated checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check_two" />
</form>
```

Assuming you have two checkboxes named differently but working in concert, this code would work

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" class="handleAsOne">
<input type="checkbox" id="2" class="handleAsOne">
```

javascript (jquery):

```
$('.handleAsOne').on('change'){
   $('.handleAsOne').prop('checked', false);
   $(this).prop('checked', true);
}
```

if i understood your question correctly you are looking for something like this.